# Export image with phantom - Navigator or credits cannot be changed

Tags: highcharts

We are trying to generate a png in server following [this one](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs).

The graphic is drawn correctly, but we cannot hide the navigator. The JSON passed to the script is:

```
"{\"constr\":\"StockChart\",\"navigator\":\"{enabled:false}\",\"infile\":\"{series: [{data:...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by: `\"navigator\":\"{enabled:false}\",` in wrong place. This should be in `infile`, on the same level as series, xAxis, etc.

Also, shouldn't be there:  `\"navigator\":{\"enabled\":false},` ?